# Return from an event handling function

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have two validation groups on my asp.net form.
I use the following C# code to prevent data from being submitted in case of invalid user input:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate("g2");
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            alert("fill the form with valid data");
            return;
        }
        //get user input and save them in database
        //in case of error, display error message
}
```

When I enter an invalid data into a text box in group "g2" and click button "btnAdd", it does not return from btnAdd_Click() as intended. Instead it seems to continue execution of statements following if(!Page.IsValid) block. Why is it so and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I don't get it; you are expecting to "finish" the execution of btnAdd_Click after the Validate method?

Comment: I think it is executing as written because !Page.IsValid means that there is some validation failed.So you need to change it to Page.IsValid if i am not wrong.

Comment: I want it to stop execution of event handling function in case validation fails